# How To Generate repo.magento.com Username and Password

Tags: magento2

I wanted to install Magento (Magento 2) community project on my local machine. I had an adobe account from the past. I went through the [installation guide](https://experienceleague.adobe.com/docs/commerce-operations/installation-guide/composer.html) and followed the instructions. I have my `keys` and the `download access token`.

But when I reached that point to create the project meta package, it stopped after the authentication. I obviously used wrong username and/or password but it stuck there and didn't give any response.

Can someone tell me where do the username and password come from?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have got the answer. I have registered my [Adobe Commerce 2 Access Keys](https://developer.magento.com/account/keys) but it was not clear that I have to use them as user name and password because I didn't read the instructions written on the UI: "These keys can be used for authorized downloads of the Adobe Commerce 2 platform, extensions, and themes. Please see the instruction document for downloading and installing the Adobe Commerce 2 platform."

[image]

```
$ composer create-project --repository-url=https://repo.magento.com/ magento/project-community-edition /path/to/magento/project
Creating a "magento/project-community-edition" project at "./magento.project"
    Authentication required (repo.magento.com):
username: public_key
password: private_key
```

I have got a video which explains it step by step: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=q2ozCtB_vKM